# Google Map Marker and coordinates in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

This is my TrackMap.java

```
public class TrackMap extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

    GoogleMap map;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_map);

        boolean lowPowerMoreImportantThanAccurancy = true;
        LocationRequest request = LocationRequest.create();
        request.setPriority(lowPowerMoreImportantThanAccurancy ? 
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY: 
                LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        // Enabling MyLocation Layer of Google Map
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(0, 0)).draggable(true)
                // Set Opacity specified as a float between 0.0 and 1.0,
                // where 0 is fully transparent and 1 is fully opaque.
                .alpha(0.7f).flat(true));

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        map.clear();

        MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

        mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        mp.title("Current Position");

        map.addMarker(mp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

My question here is how should I do to let user add marker on maps and my TrackMap.java able to get the coordinate and save in a variable. How should I do that?

From what I search online , they just teach markers with known coordinates. But now I would like to let user to add marker without knowing the coordinates.

Comment: It is better if can provide me some source code that add marker without knowing the coordinates (this code happen after user add the marker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about adding a marker at where the user touches on the map? Here is the code:

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
          map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point));
          // you can get latitude and longitude also from 'point'
          // and using Geocoder, the address
         }
});
```

Comment: Now once I got the points, How can I separate the points into latitude and longitude so that I can save in 2 variables and then save into MySQL?

Comment: We have `LatLng point`. From that, we get as `point.latitude` & `point.longitude`

Answer (score 1):

You can use geocoding for that. Geocoding is the process of transforming a street address or other description of a location into a (latitude, longitude) coordinate. And once you get the coordinate you can add the marker there.

Comment: It is better if can provide me some source code that user add marker without knowing the coordinates and address(this code happen after user add the marker).

Comment: This link may help you http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/locating-user-input-address-in-google-maps-android-api-v2-with-geocoding-api/

Comment: @Kat-hat this link helps me find the pinpoint according to the address, but I really don't know how to get the coordinate

Answer (score 0):

There can be a few steps in doing so:-

1. Give a button to the user to mark his/her current location.
2. OnClick of that button, get the current location and save it in your file/database etc.
3. Add a marker on the map using the stored location and notify the user

Comment: nono not the current location, because user can be anywhere and the user want to add his/her house location

Comment: then you give him an option to add a marker on the map, set its property to draggable, and let the user drag that marker to his/her desired location. Now when he is done, get the geo-coordinates from the position and save it. You can search, how to get the geo-code location of a place when the marker is dragged in android google maps

Comment: ok... I just need to try to get the coordinates if got source code better